# Discord.js adding 3 reactions to a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The question is in the title! In the console, it says that there is a missing ). I don’t know where though... Here is my code so far:

`message.react("").then(() => message.react("⛹️").then(() => message.react("")));`

To be clear, in the console it says this: `Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ‘)’`

Comment: You also missed a dot. It should be like following:
message.react('').then(() => message.react('⛹️')).then(() => message.react(''));

Comment: Please look at your code. At a simple glance I found that you are missing a `.` on one `then()`

Comment: Yes, I added the . now. Check the edits

Comment: I know the issue, however you're better off learning basic javascript if you're unable to see it yourself. Its a very simple error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message.react("")
.then(() => message.react("⛹️"))
.then(() => message.react(""));
```

i think you typo on

```
.then(() => message.react("")));
```